# Issue installing geos pod, a dependancy for GEOSwift

Tags: ios, cocoapods, geos

I was trying to install **GEOSwift** pod in a project that I was working on.
One of the dependencies of that pod is the **geos** pod. I keep getting the following error every time I run `pod install`.

```
Updating local specs repositories
Analyzing dependencies
Downloading dependencies
Installing GEOSwift (0.3.0)
Installing geos (3.4.2)
[!] /bin/bash -c
set -e

type -P autoconf &>/dev/null || alias autoconf 'xcrun autoconf'
type -P autoheader &>/dev/null || alias autoheader 'xcrun autoheader'
type -P aclocal &>/dev/null || alias aclocal 'xcrun aclocal'
type -P automake &>/dev/null || alias automake 'xcrun automake'
type -P glibtool &>/dev/null || alias glibtool 'xcrun glibtool'
type -P glibtoolize &>/dev/null || alias glibtoolize 'xcrun glibtoolize'

sh autogen.sh
./configure
./tools/svn_repo_revision.sh

sed -i "" "s/\/\* #undef HAVE_INT64_T_64 \*\//#define HAVE_INT64_T_64 1/" include/geos/platform.h
sed -i "" "s/#define HAVE_LONG_INT_64 1/\/\* #undef HAVE_LONG_INT_64 \*\//" include/geos/platform.h

cat <<EOT >> include/geos/platform.h
  #undef ISNAN
  #define ISNAN(x) (std::isnan(x))
EOT

/bin/bash: line 5: alias: aclocal: not found
/bin/bash: line 5: alias: xcrun aclocal: not found
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was a couple of tools that I was missing.

Fixed the problem by running the following commands in a terminal:

- `brew install autoconf`
- `brew install automake`

You might have to run them as superuser by adding `sudo` in front of them and putting in your password.

**NOTE:** If you do not have **Homebrew** installed already, you can follow the instructions here: http://brew.sh

Comment: Trying to `sudo brew install`, you'll get this Error: Cowardly refusing to `sudo brew install` You can use brew with sudo, but only if the brew executable is owned by root. However, this is both not recommended and completely unsupported so do so at your own risk.